# How to Object.defineProperty on custom window object in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, window

For instance I have YOTI object injected into browser:

When I run this in console:

> ```
> window.YOTI
> ```

I get:

```
{onShare: ƒ, redirect: ƒ}
```

Then if I access redirect method I get this:

> ```
> window.YOTI.redirect
> ```

```
ƒ (callbackUrl, token) {
                var currentQuery =  window.location.search.replace('?','')
                var currentFragment = window.location.hash
                var separator = (callbackU…
```

I want to modify this property in angular onInit() and I tried this from here(https://yoti.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008958873-Does-the-Yoti-frontend-client-support-an-Angular-App-):

```
const ytcontainer = {
};

Object.defineProperty(window, 'YOTI', {
  get: () => ytcontainer.YOTI,

  set: yoti => {
    ytcontainer.YOTI = yoti;

    Object.defineProperty(yoti, 'redirect', {
      get: () => {
        return (callbackUrl, token) => {
          console.log(callbackUrl);
          console.log(token);
        };
      },
    });
  },
});
```

but after that, when I run window.YOTI I get undefined object.

```
window.YOTI
undefined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps a protection on YOTI object done somewhere. Try preserve `window.YOTI` and play with another variable, local or global like `window.yotiProxy`. To log call YOTI methods, you can use a Proxy with an apply handler: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/apply